# background-clip: text working in 1 browser window but not the other?

Tags: html, css

I know on the website [arc.dev](https://arc.dev), there is the usage of the `background-clip: text` property.

[image: Screenshot]

I looked at the source, and the HTML is:

```
<span class="sc-b8c3677-0 hxpAlL">remote job search</span>
```

Right click -> copy styles gives me:

```
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height: 51px;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-size: 200%;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-color: rgb(56, 123, 255);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(162, 68, 255) 0%, rgb(52, 182, 255) 50%, rgb(162, 68, 255) 100%);
    animation: 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none running bHafHd;
```

which I turn into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      .foo {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: -0.02em;
        font-size: 46px;
        line-height: 51px;
        box-sizing: inherit;
        display: inline-block;
        background-position-x: 0px;
        background-size: 200%;
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        background-color: rgb(56, 123, 255);
        background-image: linear-gradient(
          90deg,
          rgb(162, 68, 255) 0%,
          rgb(52, 182, 255) 50%,
          rgb(162, 68, 255) 100%
        );
        animation: 3s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal none running bHafHd;
      }
    </style>
    <span class="foo">remote job search</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this fails to render properly. My browser says that `background-clip: text` is an invalid property value, even though I know it's rendering correctly in my browser, on arc.dev.

What am I doing wrong?

Their page:
[image: Their Page]

My page:
[image]

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Chrome doesn't support `text` for `background-clip`, only `-webkit-background-clip` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)). However, it appears to be working fine on arc.dev. I don't know why that block is in italics, uneditable, and the style element is empty (and I couldn't find that class anywhere else but the element), though...

Comment: For your own use, you could include `-webkit-background-clip` as well as `background-clip`. I'll continue investigating arc.dev...

Comment: Should I write an answer of some sort based on what I've got so far? Or is that not useful enough yet?

Comment: Ah, the style element has the `data-styled` attribute, and the page is built using React. I guess it's using some CSS-in-JS.

Comment: Found! The "index" under Sources in DevTools has the block, and it has both the regular and the prefixed property. All something to do with Styled Components (CSS-in-JS). I also have a vague recollection of Chrome hiding prefixed versions of properties, in addition to it sometimes showing shorthands instead of longhands.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Some browsers support `text` only with `-webkit-background-clip`, not `background-clip`. Use both properties so that non-supporting browsers can fall back to the prefixed property.

*I assume you are using Chrome.*

Some browsers still do not support the `text` value for the `background-clip` property, only for the prefixed version, `-webkit-background-clip`. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) for the full details. Currently it is Chrome, Opera, and Samsung Internet.

As to the copying, [Arc](https://arc.dev) uses React and Styled Components (see Research section). Because of Chrome DevTools's behavior with Styled Components (I believe the styles are dynamically added), it does not show the prefixed property, only the normal one, and does not show any warnings. Hence, the styles you copied included only the unprefixed property, which does not actually support the `text` value in Chrome.

**The solution is to use both `-webkit-background-clip` and `background-clip`,** so that browsers that do not support `text` with the unprefixed property can fall back to the prefixed property.

### Demo

The following demo has two lines of text, the first with only the unprefixed property and the second with both the unprefixed and the prefixed properties.

I've slimmed down the styles a bit. A lot of it was for backwards compatibility (the fallback background in case `background-image` with a gradient is not supported, etc.).

```css
.normal {
  background-clip: text;
}

.both {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

/* Base styles */

.text {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  font-size: 46px;
  line-height: 51px;
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgb(162, 68, 255) 0%,
    rgb(52, 182, 255) 50%,
    rgb(162, 68, 255) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<span class="text normal">remote job search</span>
<br>
<span class="text both">remote job search</span>
```

### Research

The element in question has the classes `sc-b8c3677-0` and `hxpAlL`.

Searching for `sc-b8c3677-0` in the scripts of [arc.dev](https://arc.dev/) (via DevTools > Application > Frames > Scripts), I found it in this:

```
g = o.default.span.withConfig({
  componentId: "sc-b8c3677-0"
})(c(), p)
```

That is Styled Components (I believe) creating a "component" with the ID of `sc-b8c3677-0`.

Styled Components then adds the class `hxpAlL` to this element.

Related code (from "(index)" in Sources):

```css
/*!sc*/
data-styled.g162[id="sc-b8c3677-0"] {
  content: "hxpAlL,"
}
```

```html
<span class="sc-b8c3677-0 hxpAlL">remote job search</span>
```

I believe the styles (from class `hxpAlL`) are dynamically added somehow, given the fact that

- they do not appear in the actual final DOM;
- they are in italics and uneditable;
- the style element the block links to is empty and has the attributes `data-styled="active"`.

I have a vague recollection of Chrome hiding prefixed versions of properties, in addition to it sometimes showing shorthands instead of longhands.
I cannot remember the exact bug reports about these, but I will try to find them.

Reasons to believe Styled Components is involved at all:

- The style element involved attributes `data-styled="active"` and `data-styled-version="5.3.6"` (the latest Styled Components version is 5.3.11).
- The style blocks in the source have a "magic comment" of `/*!sc*/` above them.
- The `o.default.span.withConfig` code matches the style of usage of Styled Components in source code.
- Its pretty common to use it with React.